# Free .txt file hosting

Tags: java, web-hosting

Is it possible to host a file (.txt) so that i can access it using java code.
I have just seen examples of reading a text file in java using Url class .
But what i want is that we can store a txt file on web and can read as well as write to that file.

I have tried searching on Google about it but could not find any. Everytime i end, with some website hosting site.

Just to make things more clear i am adding a pseudo code of what i want.

```
Url fileUrl=new Url("LOCATION TO MY FILE ON WEB");
```

And some code to write to the file.
I have seen fileUrl.openStream() , but it returns a InputStream object.

Is it possible to achieve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It is possible to host a text file (.txt) which can be retrieved with Java code.**

There is **no** need for any *special kind of server* for this. It can be done with any web server.

You don't necessarily need to buy server space, instead you can use the different free web hosting sites available on the Internet. Though if you are going to do this for long term then buying server space is recommended.

*For example:*
If your server name is myserver.com, and you host the file (sample.txt) in a folder called data inside your server, then the url: `myserver.com/data/sample.txt` can be used to retrieve it.

Example for Reading Java Code( using Java URL Class):

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.net.*;  
public class textRetrive{  
    public static void main(String[] args){  
        try{  
            URL url=new URL("http://www.myserver.com/data/sample.txt");  

            System.out.println("Protocol: "+url.getProtocol());  
            System.out.println("Host Name: "+url.getHost());  
            System.out.println("Port Number: "+url.getPort());  
            System.out.println("File Name: "+url.getFile());  

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }  
    }  
}
```

**For modifying a text file hosted on a server is a lot difficult.** 
First and foremost you would need to have **access** and **sufficient privilege** of the server.
You can modify a file hosted using some kind of **FTP connection** or **SSH connection**.

1. With FTP connection, you will need to upload a modified version of
   the file from your local system to the server. You can achieve this
   using

> [Apache Commons Net API](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/) for uploading files by FTP protocol

2. Using SSH connection, you will basically run commands on the web server remotely. In java you can use this by

> [JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) Library

*In essence you would need to build a robust Java program which can either upload files using FTP or run commands remotely using SSH*

Comment: But how will i write to the file from its url

Comment: If it is possible to write to a file just from its url then everybody will be writing anywhere

Comment: I cant see anywhere in your code where you have write to the file.

Comment: https://howtodoinjava.com/java-8/java-8-write-to-file-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can host it to your server and then use the location of the file as the URL. You can use some free hosting website.

Comment: How can i write to that file.

Comment: And if i can write to it just using the url then anybody could write anywhere

Comment: On the cpanel there is the option of the file permissions. Just grant it to all read, write permissions.

Comment: But then also what is the code to write to the file.

Comment: Scanner is for reading only not for writing.

Comment: Sorry, Have you tried simple file handling on it? I had done it in my project but It may be something missing